# Roskam assumptions in order to calculate speed of sound formula, need explanation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, acoustics

As you can see inside this following link:
https://books.google.it/books?id=bSq-cEf0EWsC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=Aerodynamic+2.3.2+The+speed+of+sound&source=bl&ots=iFRByWKpwG&sig=MpcRIKUA6tsAwsEzG5lwOnRuySQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfjb_o0dXSAhWLOxQKHRjIB40Q6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=Aerodynamic%202.3.2%20The%20speed%20of%20sound&f=false
Jan Roskam's book : Airplane Aerodynamics and Performance, Chapter 2 Basic Aerodynamic Principles and Application, Subparagraph 2.3.2 THE SPEED OF SOUND, I don't understand completely the assumptions, the hypothesi taken by book author: in particular the book says: " To derive an expression for the speed of sound c, consider a one-dimensional duct with an infinitesimal pressure wave generated inside the gas at rest. If a coordinate system is chosen to be fixed with the disturbance, the gas velocity, $V_a$ will be the propagation speed of the disturbance before being affected by it. " Please explain better if possible. Only what I understand is that the book with this assumptions permit to identify  "the gas velocity, $V_a$" with speed of sound that is a velocity (speed) of disturbance, so with those hypothesis it identifyies (at least about speed calculation) at the end liquid material motion with disturbance motion. With the good intention for the results I still have to undertsand better the assumptions I quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very poor explanation IMO. What he is trying to do is consider a pulse of pressure moving along the tube and find its velocity, but he doesn't describe the assumptions clearly, and some diagrams would be useful!

This derivation follows the same idea, but with more explanation: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Introduction_to_Physical_Chemistry_Lecture_5_Supplement.pdf

Personally I prefer a different approach that sets up a differential equation (the wave equation) and then solves it, as in the Feynman lectures. It's longer, but doesn't need so many "imaginative jumps" to get from one step to the next. See http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_47.html